# xll work only on build computer

Tags: c#, excel, xll

I create *.xll with [XLW](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/) lib. But it work only on build computer. If i rebuild my project on other computer xll work on it, but not my computer. Anybody have idea from this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a classic case of you needing to deploy the runtime libraries of your tools to the machines which run the software. Your dev machines will have the necessary runtimes already. Exactly how to do that depends on which compiler you are using. The quick and dirty approach would be to link statically to the runtime.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot to copy the additional dll that used my function.

Comment: Hello @ArtemRomanov! Can you tell how to copy additional dll? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you use http://xll.codeplex.com the default is to link with static libraries. Should work on any machine.